# How to add gameobjects via script in the hierarchy in edit mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I would like to create a menu item that can build a game object with children and components. 
I can't use prefabs for the whole objects because I need that the  children are separate prefabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
[MenuItem("YOUR_MENU_NAME/YOUR_SUBMENU_NAME/YOUR_METHOD_NAME %&n")]
static void CreateAPrefab()
{
    //Parent
    GameObject prefab = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Object>("Assets/Prefabs/TestPrefab.prefab"));
    prefab.name = "TestPrefab";

    if(Selection.activeTransform != null)
    {
        prefab.transform.SetParent(Selection.activeTransform, false);
    }
    prefab.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    prefab.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
    prefab.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

    //Child 1
    GameObject prefabChild1 = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Object>("Assets/Prefabs/TestPrefabChild1.prefab"));
    prefabChild1.name = "TestPrefabChild";

    prefabChild1.transform.SetParent(prefab.transform, false);
    prefabChild1.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    prefabChild1.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
    prefabChild1.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

    //Child2...
    //...

    Selection.activeGameObject = prefab;
}
```

Don't forget to include `using UnityEditor;` and to either place the script in an **Editor/** folder or use `#if UNITY_EDITOR / #endif` around the parts using the editor methods. Also I added a shortcut to the [MenuItem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html) using `%&n` (Ctrl + Alt + N).

If you need to change the prefabs that compose the instantiated object, you can try to retrieve them all in your project (maybe be and heavy operation depending on your project) as they did [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/editor-want-to-check-all-prefabs-in-a-project-for-an-attached-monobehaviour.253149/) and display a kind of checklist where you select the prefabs needed as children inside an [EditorWindow](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.GetWindow.html).

Comment: That's exacty what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it helped!